# Use of "customer" to describe a member of another team

Tags: professionalism, new-job, team, email

I just got hired as a part-time Web Technician at a University this past Monday, today, one of my supervisors asked me to help out another staff member from another department on their website.

I was able to solve the task and also offer some not too technical tips to this staff member. A few minutes after getting back to the office, the staff I just left her office sent an email to my department thanking them for sending me their way and how nice I was.

The email was then forwarded to me with an extra line that looks like,

`"Hey John, nice complement here from Doe"`.

Then my response was

`Yay! One "customer" down, many to go"`

After sending the email, I began to doubt if my usage of `"customer"` was appropriate.

`Customer` was quoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In every company I've worked so far, we had customers. Be it internal or external customers.

In this case, she is an internal customer, because she requested something from your department and she is an employee of the same company as you.

Answer (score 2):

You're worrying too much.

Whether your use of the word "customer" in this context was standard or not we can't know and is going to depend on your workplace. If it's not standard, I really doubt anyone would care. It's clear what you meant, it's not derogatory, and even if your manager prefers you call them by another name, you're the new person, so it's easily forgivable. If your manager really cares that much, they will tell you.

So relax, stop sweating about it, and move on.